# Can anyone help me with this INSERT SQL statement?

Tags: sql, database, insert

I have a table like the following:

```
owner Pet
__________
Bob   Joe
Sam   Rob
Bob   George
Phil  Marge
```

Now, I want to create an INSERT statement for a new Owner, Nick. I want to make my insert statement such that for every pet that Bob owns, Nick owns one of the same name.

I'm trying to do this to accomplish my task:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES ('Nick', Pet)
SELECT Pet FROM Table T
WHERE T.owner = 'Bob')
```

But the above isn't working. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (owner, Pet)
SELECT 'Nick', Pet FROM Table WHERE owner = 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it.

```
Insert Into Table (Pet, Owner)
Select Pet, 'Nick' From Table Where Owner = 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we make it even simpler?

```
SELECT 'Nick', pet INTO table FROM table WHERE Owner = 'Bob'
```

Comment: Select INTO creates a new table.

Comment: @Randy Minder: On SQL Server only -- in Oracle, it's used to populate variables.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @OMG Ponies, guess thats what I get for using Oracle somtetimes
@marc_s, I usually do, just forgot this time, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

this will do what you want:

```
create table t_test3 ( ownr varchar(20) not null, pet varchar(20) not null);
insert into t_test3 (ownr, pet) values ('bob', 'joe');
insert into t_test3 (ownr, pet) values ('sam', 'rob');
insert into t_test3 (ownr, pet) values ('bob', 'george');
insert into t_test3 (ownr, pet) values ('phil', 'marge');

insert into t_test3 
     select 'nick', pet from t_test3 where ownr = 'bob';

select * from t_test3;
```

Answer (score 0):

store pet inna var and use in second query.

```
SELECT Pet INTO @PET FROM Table WHERE owner = 'Bob')
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Nick', @PET)
```

Thats what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT Pets (owner, Pet)
SELECT 'Nick', Pet
FROM Pets
WHERE owner = 'Bob'
```

Assuming your table is named 'Pets'.  Run the Select without the insert to see the rows that will be inserted first.